# BSONObj size: 19033121 (0x1226C21) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: operationTime: Timestamp(1619116787, 2)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

all when I try to run my query on the server it's showing this error is there any way to fix this issue.

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: BSONObj size: 19033121 (0x1226C21) is invalid. Size must be between 0 and 16793600(16MB) First element: operationTime: Timestamp(1619116787, 2)
Apr 22 18:39:49 ip-10-0-2-119 web: at Connection.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:451:61)
Apr 22 18:39:49 ip-10-0-2-119 web: at Connection.emit (events.js:310:20)
Apr 22 18:39:49 ip-10-0-2-119 web: at Connection.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
Apr 22 18:39:49 ip-10-0-2-119 web: at processMessage (/var/app/current/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:451:10)
Apr 22 18:39:49 ip-10-0-2-119 web: at Socket.<anonymous> (/var/app/current/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connection.js:620:15)
Apr 22 18:39:49 ip-10-0-2-119 web: at Socket.emit (events.js:310:20)
Apr 22 18:39:49 ip-10-0-2-119 web: at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:482:12)
Apr 22 18:39:49 ip-10-0-2-119 web: at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:286:12)
Apr 22 18:39:49 ip-10-0-2-119 web: at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:268:9)
Apr 22 18:39:49 ip-10-0-2-119 web: at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:209:10)
Apr 22 18:39:49 ip-10-0-2-119 web: at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:186:23)
```

Comment: as far as I see, your request to the server is bigger than 16MB which is not allowed

Comment: In MongoDB a document must not bigger than 16MiByte, it's a fixed limit. Change your query (since you did not provide the query nor any sample data I cannot give you a better answer)

Comment: Thnaks @dododo and @ Wernfried Domscheit my query is already optimized as I can or indexes are also added

Comment: not sure whether you said that it's already fixed or no, but if no, the question is not about query complexity, but about the size of the document that will be sent to the server, in this case, the size is bigger than 16MB (probably big payload)

Answer (score 0):

We need to create a indexes on mongo db tables. this problem is resolved